# Screenshot is not working with chrome browser but same code is working fine with firefox

Tags: selenium-webdriver, screenshot

CaptureScreenShot.java:

```
public class CaptureScreenshot {
    WebDriver driver;
          
          public static void takescreenshot(WebDriver driver,String Screenshotname) throws IOException
           {
                  TakesScreenshot takescreenshot=(TakesScreenshot)driver;
                  File source=takescreenshot.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                  FileUtils.copyFile(source, new File("./Screenshots/"+Screenshotname+".png"));
                  System.out.println("Screenshot Taken Successfully!!!!");
                 
           }
```

Main.java:

```
public class testLogin extends SuperTestNG {
    


@BeforeClass
    public void precondition()
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:/personal/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://10.1.19.234:8002/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        
    }
    @Test()
    public void login1()
    {
        
        Login login=new Login(driver);
        login.testLogin();
        //login.clkUsers();
        Assert.assertEquals("Index - testw", "Index - test");
    }
    
    @AfterMethod
    public void failedCondi(ITestResult result) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Testcase status is"+ result.getStatus());
        System.out.println("result status is"+ ITestResult.FAILURE);
        if(ITestResult.FAILURE==result.getStatus())
        {
            CaptureScreenshot.takescreenshot(driver, "titlefail");
        }
        
    }

}
```

This code is working fine with Firefox browser but same code is giving following error with Chrome browser.

```
Error: FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod failedCondi([TestResult name=login1 status=FAILURE method=TestLogin.login1()[pri:0, instance:script.TestLogin@523884b2] output={null}])
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot get automation extension
from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html
  (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

Comment: Have you tried to update to the latest chromedriver version?

Comment: I have updated my chrome Driver and now its working...but its taking half page screen shot only.Is there a way to take failed test cases screenshot only

Comment: Make sure that you're setting window size of webdriver correctly

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 2):

I think that Chrome is still not fully supporting taking screenshots with web driver. Take a look at this outstanding issues on Chromedriver project:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1083

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=294